# 3-Level Nested Array in PHP & MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to create a nested array, in order to produce a nested list within a webpage.

So far I have managed to get the following:

```
    Array
(
[2012] => Array
    (
        [Show 1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Class 1
            )

        [Show 2] => Array
            (
                [0] => Class 1
            )

    )

[2009] => Array
    (
        [Show 1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Class 1
            )

    )

[2008] => Array
    (
        [Show 1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Class 1
            )

    )

)
```

However my actual results have more than 1 class per show, so it should look like:

```
[2012] => Array
    (
        [Show 1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Class 1
                [1] => Class 2
                [2] => Class 3
            )
etc etc etc.
```

I've managed this far, but haven't a clue how to continue, in order to get more than one class per show.

My code is as follows:

```
$handlerresults = $db->query("SELECT SHOW_NAME, YEAR, CLASS_NAME FROM vwhandlerresults WHERE HANDLER_ID = $gethandlerid ORDER BY YEAR DESC");
$showname = '';
while($row = $handlerresults->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$year = $row['YEAR'];
$show = $row['SHOW_NAME'];
$results[$year][$show] = array($row['CLASS_NAME']);
}
print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
$results[$year][$show] = array($row['CLASS_NAME']);
```

to

```
$results[$year][$show][] = $row['CLASS_NAME']
```

I think the problem is that you're overwriting your array each time you pass through the loop with the same 'show'. If you do what I said above, instead of overwriting, it'll put the next class into the next available index.

Comment: Perfect! Now I've just got to figure out how to get this into a nested UL list.

Comment: Good luck! That should be a bit easier, but feel free to come back and ask if you have trouble :)

Comment: Can I ask about the unordered list here, or should I open a new thread?

Comment: You should probably open a new thread seeing as it's sort of a different topic. Post the link here if you like and I'll take a look.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775361/nested-array-to-3-level-unordered-list