# Nested array to 3-level unordered list

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a nested array, and am looking to turn it into an unordered list:

```
[2009] => Array
    (
        [Show Name 1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Class 1
                [1] => Class 2
            )

    )

[2008] => Array
    (
        [Show Name 2] => Array
            (
                [0] => Class 1
                [1] => Class 2
            )

    )
```

And turn that into:

```
2009
    Show Name 1
        Class 1
        Class 2
2008
    Show Name 2
        Class 1
        Class 2
```

So far I have partially managed it, by being able to show the Year, but after that I get 'array' where the show name should be:

```
2012
    Array
    Array
2009
    Array
2008
    Array
```

I made that using the following:

```
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $results as $year => $shows ): ?>
    <li><?= $year ?>
      <ul>
        <?php foreach( $shows as $show ): ?>
        <li><?= $show ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

---

**Update**

I need to grab the YEAR_ID, SHOW_ID, CLASS_ID for each result, so that I can pass them into a URL. Something like:

```
        <ul class="no-bullet">
        <?php foreach( $results as $year => $shows ): ?>
        <li><h2><?= $year ?></h2>
          <ul class="no-bullet">
            <?php foreach( $shows as $show_name => $show ): ?>
            <li><h4><?= $show_name ?></h4></li>
                 <ul class="no-bullet">
                      <?php foreach( $show as $class ): ?>
                      <li><a href="results.html?year=$yearid&show=$showid&class=$classid"><?= $class ?></a></li>
                      <?php endforeach; ?>
                 </ul>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

However, I haven't the foggiest where to start. I considered a query within the foreach loop, but figured that may be quite inefficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to treat the `$show` as an array and just extract the part you want, something like this:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach( $results as $year => $shows ): ?>
    <li><?= $year ?>
      <ul>
        <?php foreach( $shows as $show_name => $show ): ?>
        <li><?= $show_name ?>
             <ul>
                  <?php foreach( $show as $class ): ?>
                  <li><?= $class ?></li>
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
             </ul>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Spot on! For educational purposes... how does it know what $class is? As it isn't defined anywhere?

Comment: Ah, but it is defined ;) It's in the `foreach` loop. `foreach( $show as $class )` means it takes the `$show` array and assigns the contents of an element to the `$class` variable for each element in the array.

Comment: To add to that: The loop itself defines the `$class` array.

Comment: Ahh I see... I may have coped but the other stackoverflow answers were either for just 2 levels, or for a nav-menu, which threw me. Thanks so much mate.

Comment: No worries. Yeah, if you have a nested array, the `$value` part of the `foreach` loop (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) will just become the nested array itself instead of a simple variable, which means you can use that as part of another `foreach` loop if desired (which is what's done here). You can nest `foreach` loops as much as you can nest arrays.

Comment: I think I need to modify my code... I've updated the previous question - would you mind taking a look @SharkofMirkwood

Answer (score 0):

You should add 3rd loop:

```
   <ul>
    <?php foreach( $results as $year => $shows ): ?>
    <li><?= $year ?>
      <ul>
        <?php foreach( $shows as $showname=>$show_list ): ?>
             <li><ul>
             <?php foreach( $show_list as $show ): ?>
                 <li><?= $show ?></li>
             <?php endforeach; ?>
             </ul>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```